# Connect HTML slider with Angular 2 component

Tags: html, angular, slider, angular2-template

I use PrimeNG as UI library within my Angular 2 app. In a certain component I require to have a slider component. Thus I've used the respective PrimeNG slider component as follows:

```
<p-slider [(ngModel)]="this.adjustedCalculation.predictionYear"></p-slider>
```

This works perfectly.

However, I noticed that this component is broken on devices with a touch screen. So I need to find a replacement.

I came across the standard HTML 5 input of type "range" described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_form_sliders.asp) and added its markup like so:

```
<input type="range" name="points" id="points" value="50" min="0" max="100" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true" />
```

How do I connect this input element with my Angular 2 component variable `this.adjustedCalculation.predictionYear`?

I want that the value the user selected is represented in this variable.

**UPDATE:**

I added `[(ngModel)]` as suggested and it works. Next point is that I want to control the min and max value of this input element. Consider the previous version of the PrimeNG slider:

```
<p-slider [(ngModel)]="this.adjustedCalculation.predictionYear" [min]="this.displayedCalculation.predictionYear - 10" [max]="this.displayedCalculation.predictionYear + 10"></p-slider>
```

How do I have to pass the expression "predictionYear - 10" resp. + 10 to that input element?
Let me know if I should rather raise a new question for this purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out my updated answer. I also updated Plunker I provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `NgModel` directive the same way you used it in `p-slider` component:

```
<input type="range" name="points" id="points" value="50" min="0"
max="100" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true" 
[(ngModel)]="this.adjustedCalculation.predictionYear" />
```

As for min and max value, simply use property binding to assign value to `min` and `max` attributes:

```
[min]="displayedCalculation.predictionYear - 10"
[max]="displayedCalculation.predictionYear + 10"
```

Note: I saw you are using `this` in your template, there's no need to do this.

Here's [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R8IBXUvAshJwSTG9lpsj?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks it works! I slighty enhanced my question above asking for setting min and max value of the input. Maybe you have also advice here.